# How do I add geom_quiver() to ggOceanMaps?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a geom_quiver ggplot() which shows the direction of movement of some animal tracks. I want to be able to visualize the bathymetry on the same plot. I can create a bathymetry plot using ggoceanmaps() but I am having issues with the different projections. ggoceanmaps is defaulting to a curved projection and geom_quiver is flat and transform_coord() does not work for the u and v portions of the quiver.

I have managed to get as far as putting them side by side but struggling to layer them with the same projection.

[image: side by side view]

```
dt <- data.frame(lon = c(20, 20, 55, 55), lat = c(-15, -70, -70, -15))

bathy <- basemap(dt, bathymetry = TRUE) + 
  geom_polygon(data = transform_coord(dt), aes(x = lon, y = lat), 
               color = "red", fill = NA)  +
  geom_spatial_point(shape = 10, stroke = 2, size = 10, color = "darkviolet", aes(x= marion_coords[1], y = marion_coords[2]))
  
quivs <-  ggplot() + geom_quiver(data = df_test, aes(x = rounded_lon, y = rounded_lat, u = avg_u, v = avg_v, col = seal_count)) + coord_map("azequidistant")
  
bathy + quivs
```

I unfortunately cannot provide the data as it is not mine but a sample geom_quiver is provided below if anyone knows how to add the bathymetry to it so I can extrapolate from there

```
quivs <- ggplot() + 
  geom_quiver(data = seals, aes(x=long, y=lat, u=delta_long, v=delta_lat)) + coord_map("azequidistant") + borders("state")
```

[image]

Comment: Transfer the data you want to plot to the same projection than used by `basemap()`. The easiest might be `ggOceanMaps::transfer_coords()`. See here: https://mikkovihtakari.github.io/ggOceanMaps/articles/ggOceanMaps.html#adding-data-to-maps

Comment: @Mikko I presume you mean transform_coord which as mentioned in my post does not update the vector values, only lat and lon